# How to keep vim's folded line highlighted as the syntax of the first line of the paragraph

Tags: vim, colors, fold

I know vim's folded color could be set by:

```
highlight Folded ...
```

But what I want is to remove this highlight(even the default config), so the folded line would be highlighted by the syntax of the first line of the folded paragraph.

Is there any way could do this?

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do bu maybe if you use fold marker for your folds you could potentially setup a custom syntax highlighting to do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

No, this unfortunately isn't possible. Vim will always apply the `Folded` highlight group. Best you can do is clear the highlighting (and remove the fold embellishments):

```
hi! link Folded Normal
set foldtext=getline(v:lnum)
```

Folding does not disturb syntax highlighting (not even regions spanning multiple lines, potentially across (partially) folded ones), so the syntax rendering seems to work independent of folding, so the syntax highlighting of the folded lines likely is / can be made available. However, the folded text does not exactly correspond to the first line, it is obtained through the [`'foldtext'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold-foldtext) option (though that usually obtains (parts of) the first folded line).

In order to support syntax highlighting, that returned String would have to be syntax-parsed (maybe partially) as if it were part of the buffer, which sounds difficult. An easier limited solution would be to either allow the foldtext expression or the syntax-highlighted first line (e.g. through `set foldtext=`), but then the possibility of a custom prefix / suffix or cutting off an overly long line would be lost. As you hopefully see, it would not be trivial to add this; Vimscript does not have a datatype for syntax-highlighted text, which would be required in some form to combine the existing foldtext expression with the highlighting information.

Comment: This is not what I want, but thank you all the same.

Comment: As I mentioned, you would probably experience broken highlighting if this feature existed. So, even if you sat down and implemented this feature (inside core VIM), I have my doubts that it would be accepted, because it cannot be made 100% correct.

Comment: I would think the whole buffer is still available in memory, so highlighting could take place on the 'expanded' buffer and then reduced to the folded representation. Too bad though, it really diminishes the readability of the folds in some cases.

Comment: @EmileVrijdags: You're probably right; my assumption of messing up the syntax probably was overly pessimistic. After all, folds can obscure parts of the buffer, and yet syntax regions that span multiple lines don't get messed up, so the syntax highlighting likely already ignores folding (at least to some extent). So it may be just a matter of "not implemented yet".